# How to reverse the order of string names?

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to be able to enter in a set number of names, and then display them in the order of them being typed, `"Our contestants printed Forwards"`. After which would be displayed in the reverse order, `"Our contestants printed Backwards"`. I managed to get the `"Forwards"` part working, but am not sure how to get the `"Backwards"` part to work. I've commented out the copied code because I was using it as a placeholder.

To be fair, I'm supposed to be using the pointer that I defined, `string *pNames`, in order to do the storing and printing. But I have absolutely no idea how that is supposed to be done.

I would appreciate any and all help that I can get on this one. Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    string *pNames;

    string names[3];

    pNames = names;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter contestant number " << counter + 1 << " > ";
        getline(cin, pNames[counter]);
    }

    cout << "Our contestants printed Forwards" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << pNames[i] << endl;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Our contestants printed Backwards" << endl;
    //for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        //cout << pNames[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I managed to get the "Forwards" part working` - but clearly have no understanding of how you did it or else the answer to the backwards part would be pretty obvious...

Comment: @John3136 so brutally honest, but yet so true.

Comment: I was planning to add "take that as a hint not a criticism" but my fingers went faster than my my brain and I couldn't be bothered editing it ;-)

Comment: I honestly love the brutality of the comments whenever I show my novice-ness when it comes to c++, it really does bring a smile to my face :) lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it'd be simple.
Just do this:

```
cout << "Out contestants printed Backwards" << endl;
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
   cout << pNames[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Well, that definitely seems to do the trick, although, in this situation, the `2` would be set to `3`. But regardless, thanks for the help!

Comment: No, since there are 3 items in the array, there can only be items 0, 1, and 2, since they start at 0. This would give values 2, 1, and 0, accessing ALL items of the array

Comment: But after compiling it, it only showed up to the second item, instead of all three.

Comment: it should be `i >= 0`. Then you'll see all 3 caracters

Comment: Maybe I messed up somewhere, but Idk, no master of programming.

Comment: Yeah, I was just testing that before I saw your comment, changing the setup from `i > 0` to `i >= 0` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I'll just fix this post so nobody gets confused :P

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to not use vector and iterators?

```
vector<string> names;

/* Fill it some way */

/* Print forward-ordered */
for(auto i = names.cbegin(); i != names.cend(); ++i)
  cout << *i << endl;

/* Print reverse-ordered */
for(auto i = names.crbegin(); i != names.crend(); ++i)
  cout << *i << endl;
```